# 2 Axes of the same size in Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to place two Axes with equal heights next to each other with `Gridspec`, they end up at the top of the figure instead of taking up all the vertical space:

[image]

How can I get two square Axes next to each other (one of them with equal aspect ratio so that circles are circular) such that they fill the figure?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dpi = 72
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [1,1]},
                               figsize=(600/dpi, 300/dpi), dpi=dpi)

x1 = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 500)
ax1.plot(x1, np.sqrt(0.25-x1**2), c='b', lw=2, alpha=0.7)
ax1.plot(x1, -np.sqrt(0.25-x1**2), c='b', lw=2, alpha=0.7)
ax1.set_xlim(-0.5, 0.5)
ax1.set_ylim(-0.5, 0.5)
ax1.axis('equal')

x2 = np.arange(2,26,2)
ax2.scatter(x2, np.random.random(x2.shape[0]))
ymin, ymax = ax2.get_ylim()
ax2.set_xlabel('x')
ax2.set_ylabel('y')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('sofig.png', dpi=dpi, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, certainly I do not understand what you mean with "they end up at the top of the figure instead of taking up all the vertical space"

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Sorry for not being clearer: I've added a figure background to show a bit better what i mean. I don't want all the dead space under my row of Axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have squared axes you might want to give adequate figsize instead of playing with gridspecs:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(600/dpi, 300/dpi), dpi=dpi)
```

Note that x dim in figsize should be y * 2.

This would fill the whole fig space and keep the squared proportions of axes.

[image]

Comment: I tried this (see my edit), but it's just squished the Axes further up the figure. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to remove `gridspec_kw` from `.subplots()` call.